# window.performance.now() equivalent in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, navigation-timing-api

I think the question is straight forward.

I'm looking for something that's similar to window.performance.now() in nodejs V8 engine.

Right now I'm just using:-

```
var now = Date.now();
//do some processing..
console.log("time elapsed:", Date.now() - now);
```

But, I read that window.performance.now() is lot more accurate than using the date because of the what's defined [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webperformance/basics/).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I would only mention that three of the reasons the author gives for the preference of the timing API in the browser wouldn't seem to apply directly to a node situation, and the fourth, the inaccuracy of Javscript time, cites an article from 2008, and I would strongly caution against relying on older material regarding Javascript performance specifics, particularly given the recent round of performance improvements all the engines have made to support "HTML5" apps.

However, in answer to your question, you should look at [`process.hrtime()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_time)

UPDATE: The [`present`](https://github.com/dbkaplun/present) package (available via `npm install present`) provides some sugar around `hrtime` if you'd like it.

***Note:*** Since the **version 8.5.0 of Node**, you can use [performance.now()](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#perf_hooks_performance_now)

Comment: Yup, that's just what I need. Thanks. I'll take a look at `present` too.

Comment: There's also the appropriately named https://www.npmjs.com/package/performance-now

Comment: Which author? Please include the context in your answer.

Comment: The author of the link posted in the original question, obviously. The question is the context. Adding it would be a redundancy, not context.

Answer (score 159):

Node v8.5.0 has added [Performance Timing API](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#perf_hooks_performance_timing_api), which includes the [`performance#now()`](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#perf_hooks_performance_now), e.g.

```
const {
  performance
} = require('perf_hooks');

console.log('performance', performance.now());
```

Comment: or ```import { performance } from "perf_hooks";```
 for modules (.mjs)

Comment: Or even better, "for modules" without the .mjs extension as that was Node.js's initial solution to the fact that they had huge problems swapping between cjs and esm formats. JS never dictated that change, and ESM code can use .js just fine, with modern Node supporting that as long as you remember to make your codebase as using modern module syntax.

Answer (score 31):

Here's a shortcut for `process.hrtime()` that returns milliseconds instead of microseconds:

```
function clock(start) {
    if ( !start ) return process.hrtime();
    var end = process.hrtime(start);
    return Math.round((end[0]*1000) + (end[1]/1000000));
}
```

Usage:

```
var start = clock();
// do some processing that takes time
var duration = clock(start);
console.log("Took "+duration+"ms");
```

Will output something like "Took 200ms"

Answer (score 17):

What about?

```
console.time('FooTimer');
// do the work
console.timeEnd('FooTimer');
```

Comment: Beware console.time() if you're using promises, await, etc.  the time()/timeEnd() pair seem to work using global state - if you time the same tag in parallel, things won't work right.

Comment: So this may work, but if you want to pragmatically hold onto that time instead this ( process.hrtime() ) is your only other 'in process' way. You could create a parent process and watch stdout, but that's a last resort. 

EDIT: Or it looks like there's the performance timing api in nodejs as of 8.5+ - https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#perf_hooks_performance_timing_api

Answer (score 4):

### **process.uptime()**

---

- [Official Node Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_uptime)

> *"The `process.uptime()` method returns the number of seconds the*
> *current Node.js process has been running.*
>
> *The return value includes fractions of a second. Use `Math.floor()` to*
> *get whole seconds."*

### **Example: Measure For Loop Execution Time**

---

```js
const nemo = ['nemo'];

function findNemo(array) {
  
  let start_time = process.uptime();

  for (let iteration = 0; iteration < array.length; iteration++) {
     if (array[iteration] === 'nemo') {
        console.log("Found Nemo");
     }
  }

  let end_time = process.uptime();

  console.log("For loop took this much time: ", end_time - start_time);
}

findNemo(nemo);
```

### **Example Output**

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Typescript version with [process.hrtime()](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_time), based on [NextLocal's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003252/window-performance-now-equivalent-in-nodejs/34970550#34970550) answer:

```
class Benchmark {

    private start = process.hrtime();

    public elapsed(): number {
        const end = process.hrtime(this.start);
        return Math.round((end[0] * 1000) + (end[1] / 1000000));
    }
}

export = Benchmark;
```

Usage:

```
import Benchmark = require("./benchmark");

const benchmark = new Benchmark();

console.log(benchmark.elapsed());
```

Answer (score 1):

To sum up and avoiding using `perf_hooks`

```
const performance = {
        now: function(start) {
            if ( !start ) return process.hrtime();
            var end = process.hrtime(start);
            return Math.round((end[0]*1000) + (end[1]/1000000));
        }
    }
console.log('performance', performance.now());
```

Comment: Why would we want to avoid `perf_hooks`?

Comment: Because it was added in Node v8.5.0 so for backwards compatibility, that maybe required in some circumstances...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

This method came into existence in version 8.5.0 of nodejs https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#perf_hooks_performance_measurement_apis